# Black screen in LWJGL

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm currently porting a game of which the code is very obfuscated due to porting from C to Java.

My problem is that some users report a black screen and no other problems (sound is working fine e.g.), with no errors showing a problem. On my pc it runs fine, and it makes for a hell of debugging.

I was wondering if anyone can post a (list of) reason(s) this might be occurring. I've read somewhere one of the issues could be using a 32 bits Java on a 64 bits system.

My code below, also opensourced at: https://code.google.com/p/jake2t/

```
    private void renderSideBySide() {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, sbsFboId);

        // Render side by side
        glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
        glPushMatrix();

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height);
        glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity ();

        glViewport(0,0,width,height);


        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

        int shaderId = sbsShader.getId();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(shaderId);

        if (postFboTextureLocation[0] < 0) {
            postFboTextureLocation[0] = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(shaderId, "leftTexture");
        }
        if (postFboTextureLocation[1] < 0) {
            postFboTextureLocation[1] = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(shaderId, "rightTexture");
        }
        if (postFboDepthTextureLocation[0] < 0) {
            postFboDepthTextureLocation[0] = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(shaderId, "leftDepthTexture");
        }
        if (postFboDepthTextureLocation[1] < 0) {
            postFboDepthTextureLocation[1] = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(shaderId, "rightDepthTexture");
        }

        // Load the images with the colors and the depth values
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, postFboTextureId[0]);
        ARBShaderObjects.glUniform1iARB(postFboTextureLocation[0], 0); 
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, postFboTextureId[1]);
        ARBShaderObjects.glUniform1iARB(postFboTextureLocation[1], 1); 
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, postFboDepthTexture[0]);
        ARBShaderObjects.glUniform1iARB(postFboDepthTextureLocation[0], 2); 
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, postFboDepthTexture[1]);
        ARBShaderObjects.glUniform1iARB(postFboDepthTextureLocation[1], 3); 

        glBegin (GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2i (0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2i (width, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2i (width, height);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2i (0, height); 
        glEnd();                                                    

        ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(0);

        // Rendering with warping
        glPopMatrix();
        glPopAttrib();

        unbindFBO();
    }

    public void drawPostFBOs() {
        renderSideBySide();

        glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
        glPushMatrix();

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height);
        glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity ();

        glViewport(0,0,width,height);


        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        int shaderId = riftShader.getId();

        ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(shaderId);

        if (sbsFboTextureLocation < 0) {
            sbsFboTextureLocation = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(shaderId, "tex");
        }

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sbsFboTextureId);
        ARBShaderObjects.glUniform1iARB(sbsFboTextureLocation, 0); 

        glBegin (GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2i (0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2i (width, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2i (width, height);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2i (0, height); 
        glEnd();                                                    

        ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(0);


        glPopMatrix();
        glPopAttrib();
    }
```

Comment: EXTFramebuffer could be the problem. Try switching to ARB or core. AFAIK some EXTs are not supported (although they should be) by newer drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common problems that OpenGL 3+ programmer doesn't consider when coding are:

## OpenGL Extensions

- use of *ARB* and *EXT* extension.
- use of correct OGL extension.
- use multiple implementation of different OGL extensions. Here is an example using C++:

  ```
  #ifndef _MESA_INVERT_
      /*** ... some codes here ... ***/ 
  #else
      /*** ... alt some codes here ... ***/ 
  #endif
  ```

Check if the video card support the following extension using:

- *[glxinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/glxinfo)* - Linux and MacOS X based system.
- *[glview](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview)* - Windows based system.

Comment: 1. Using core over extensions is better except for old hardware, so why should this bug be due to that? 2. LWJGL (or rather GLFW) does not require an explicit ogl version to be set, as it uses the newest one (including all available extensions) by default.